# Typo3 tx news related files download counter

Tags: typo3, counter

I have a question about the `TYPO3` Extension [News System 2.3.0](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/latest/singlehtml/).

If you add related files to a news, is it possible to show a download counter 
or a counter that count how many users that have clicked the "Related File" !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of the TYPO3 News extension.

You could try to create an own extension which extend the TYPO3 News extension by the functionality needed.

Your extension could include the following

- Add a new property (e.g. downloads) to the Domain Model `Tx_News_Domain_Model_File`
- An action (e.g. `downloadFileAction($fileUid)`), that increases the download counter and redirects the user to the file download
- A ViewHelper, which renders the link to the new action for the file download

Also you should make some security considerations like "user can only download files she/he has access to".